# Determining Increasing or Decreasing Values based on Sequential Rows Per Key

Tags: python, list, direction

I have a dataset of 90,000 records. These 90,000 records belong to about 3,000 unique Keys. For each Key, the values are ordered starting with an ItemNumber of 1 and going up to 'n'.

For each Key 1 to n, I want to compare the 2nd row to the first row, the 3rd row to the 2nd row and so on. A sample of my table is given below with some values populated as an example of what's expected.

I have a column for milepost values and want to know whether the values are ascending or descending between consecutive records.

Example image found at URL: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCg2z.png since I am too new to embed a picture.

I am very new to python and am having trouble getting started. Even if I can compare "ProjectKey A, ItemNum 2" to "ProjectKey A, ItemNum 1" to know that it's ascending what can I compare the 1st record to? I am having trouble determining which direction to parse.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: 
Snippet as a csv

ProjectKey,ItemNum,BMP,Direction
A,1,0.2,_
A,2,1.7,_
A,3,2.5,_
A,4,5,_
A,5,9,_
A,6,12,_
B,1,25,_
B,2,24.2,_
B,3,21.7,_
B,4,20.3,_
C,1,3,_
C,2,4,_
C,3,5,_
C,4,6,_
C,5,5,_
C,6,4,_
C,7,3,_
C,8,2,_

Comment: Please provide the data as a text snippet as you need to import data to Python anyway. In addition what have you done so far?

Comment: Ok, thanks. I have provided the snippet in the body.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have transferred the data to text, you could use a set of lists and a for loop to parse through and compare:

```
keylistA = [0.2, 1.7, 2.5, 5, 9, 12]
listAdirection = ['(start)']

for i in range(0, len(keylistA)):
    if keylistA[i] > keylistA[i+1]:
        listAdirection.append('DESC')
    elif keylistA[i] < keylistA[i+1]:
        listAdirection.append('ASC')
    else:
        listAdirection.append('SAME')
```

This would give you some lists like this:

```
listAdirection = ['(start)', 'ASC', 'ASC', 'ASC', 'ASC', 'ASC']
```

You could have the lists saved in a nested list format, or using some sort of dictionary setup.  Of course, this is all highly dependent on how you choose to export the data from those columns into text.

Comment: Would it be possible to nest a "KeyListX" range. So something like: 

for i in range:
  if KeyList[0][0] > KeyList[0][1]
  ...
  if KeyList[1][0] > KeyList[1][1]
  ...